# where is vagrant directory is located in mac?

Tags: vagrant

I just installed **vagrant** on Mac, but when I `ssh` the I do

```
cd vagrant
```

I only got :

```
vagrant: Not a directory
```

In windows it was easy, just `cd /vagrant` works.

Thanks,

Comment: The two paths are different. `cd vagrant` is not the same as `cd /vagrant`

Comment: It is installed in a hidden folder by default, in your user directory: 

cd ~/.vagrant.d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `uninstall.tool` I found the following paths:

- `/opt/vagrant`
- `/usr/local/bin/vagrant`

Generally you can quickly locate a command with:

```
whereis vagrant
```

Comment: `whereis vagrant` doesn't  return anything in bash you need to use `which vagrant`